# ggsave error with wmf unused argument (bg = "white")

Tags: r, ggplot2, metafile, ggsave

ggsave in ggplot (3.3.4) generates this error:

> Error in grDevices::win.metafile(...) : unused argument (bg = "white")

However, I ***can*** export the plot interactively using the RStudio | Plots menu.

reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
e <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy))
e + geom_point()
ggsave("test.wmf")
ggsave("test.emf")
```

> Saving 8.98 x 5.98 in image
>
> Error in grDevices::win.metafile(...) : unused argument (bg = "white")

```
ggsave("test.emf")
```

> Saving 8.98 x 5.98 in image
>
> Error in grDevices::win.metafile(...) : unused argument (bg = "white")

Some further trouble-shooting suggests that the problem is with ggsave because this code works fine:

```
library(tidyverse)
e <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy))
e <- e + geom_point()
win.metafile("test.wmf")
print(e)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug in ggplot2 3.3.4 was resolved in ggplot2 3.3.5.